# Using transform_lookup for an Altair choropleth figure

Tags: python, altair

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to use the transform_lookup method for a choropleth figure in Altair. I've put together an example. I'm simply trying to color the states based on the latitude of the state capital. Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature='states')

state_abbr = pd.read_csv('https://worldpopulationreview.com/static/states/name-abbr.csv', names=['state', 'abbr'])
capitals = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasperdebie/VisInfo/master/us-state-capitals.csv')
capitals.columns = ['state', 'city', 'lat', 'lon']
capitals = pd.merge(capitals, state_abbr, how='left', on='state')
```

I think I need an "id" field in my dataframe. How is the id determined in the Vega dataset? I have tried sorting by state name or state abbreviation.

```
capitals = capitals.sort_values('abbr')
capitals['id'] = range(1, len(capitals) + 1)
print(capitals.head())

        state         city        lat         lon abbr  id
1      Alaska       Juneau  58.301598 -134.420212   AK   1
0     Alabama   Montgomery  32.377716  -86.300568   AL   2
3    Arkansas  Little Rock  34.746613  -92.288986   AR   3
2     Arizona      Phoenix  33.448143 -112.096962   AZ   4
4  California   Sacramento  38.576668 -121.493629   CA   5
```

And now the Altair code with the transform_lookup method.

```
base = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(fill='lightgray', stroke='black', strokeWidth=0.5)

chart = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(stroke='black').encode(
    color='lat:Q'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(capitals, 'id', ['lat'])
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).project('albersUsa')

base + chart
```

[image: incorrect coloring]

However, the figure is clearly wrong. The states should be colored darkest in the north and lightest in the south based on latitude. Also, some states with names later in the alphabet are missing data? I need help matching my Pandas dataframe with the Vega state dataset.

Answer (score 3):

This [comment on github](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4090848#gistcomment-2102151) was key. The id field in the us_10m dataset is based on their ANSI standardized code which can be found [here](https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/state.txt).

Working code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature='states')

# per https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4090848#gistcomment-2102151
ansi = pd.read_csv('https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/reference/state.txt', sep='|')
ansi.columns = ['id', 'abbr', 'state', 'statens']
ansi = ansi[['id', 'abbr', 'state']]

capitals = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasperdebie/VisInfo/master/us-state-capitals.csv')
capitals.columns = ['state', 'city', 'lat', 'lon']
capitals = pd.merge(capitals, ansi, how='left', on='state')

base = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(fill='lightgray', stroke='black', strokeWidth=0.5)

chart = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(stroke='black').encode(
    color='lat:Q'
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(capitals, 'id', ['lat'])
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).project('albersUsa')

base + chart
```

[image]